# Specify order of slides in carousel?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is there a way to control the order of slides displayed to users in a carousel from the Experience Editor perspective? (or even the Content Editor)

Basically, based on the user that has been identified or not identified, I would like to display a different slide as the first slide of the carousel.  All the other slides would still be present, just in a different, specified order.

Is there a way to accomplish this via rules or should I look at having to create separate datasources that have the different slide orders already specified?

Comment: How do you display slides at all? Are these separate renderings? What do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kevin.  Building from scratch and was trying to architect to accommodate the requirements.  Were I just creating a 'standard' carousel, I would have carousel items in Sitecore that would contain images, text, CTA buttons, etc.  The carousel would be a single rendering.  Then, allow the content author to select carousel items via rendering parameters to be displayed.  Order would be controlled by the order in which the carousel item was in the multilist data field.

Comment: You might want to look at the TreeList field type. You can order the selected items in that control.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Personalization can do three things:

- vary a datasource for a rendering
- vary a rendering (use another rendering basically)
- hide a rendering.

I guess the question you need to answer is **whether what you need can be accomplished by doing either one of these actions**.

If you've used nested structures to represent your carousel (like we do in [SCORE](http://brainjocks.com/company/score), you can see how it looks like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWYAGc7S6M) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVvhE069ueY)) it's not hard to show/hide certain panels based on personalization conditions and thus reorder the carousel. Depending on how exactly it looks on the published site you may only need to repoint datasources. Either way, it's personalization out of the box and your content structures working nicely together.

If you've used a (variation of a) `MultiList` field to represent a list of your panels with panels themselves being items somewhere in the shared content area it's not something personalization engine can change based on a condition. **Changing a field value is, unfortunately, not on the menu**. I am sure you can *code* around it thanks to Sitecore being so open and flexible but I am not sure you can make it seamless (e.g. variations preview in Page Editor).

Rendering parameters is also not something you can change but if yours are *static* and defined on the rendering definition item (as opposed to being supplied when component is bound to the placeholder and thus recorded inside the [presentation details](http://jockstothecore.com/solid-liquid-gas-three-states-of-layout-details/)) you can get away with having two definition items for your carousel component (same code behind it) and picking the right one based on the personalization condition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! Not ignoring, just trying to digest and figure out how it applies to my particular situation.